# When does a Stream need to be lazy?

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation

The following are both meant to create a Stream of integers:

```
val s: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: s.map(_ + 1)

def makeStream = {
  val s: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: s.map(_ + 1)
  s
}
```

The first is fine; however the `makeStream` method won't compile:

```
error: forward reference extends over definition of value s
  val s: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: s.map(_ + 1)
                             ^
```

It only compiles if we make `s` a `lazy val`. Why does it need to be a `lazy val` in a method, but not outside?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside a class, a `val` definition decompiles into an "getter" method that references a hidden class field. These "getter" methods can be self-referential (or rather, the class initializer can reference the "getter") because this is the semantics of Java methods. Note that your "outside" definition of `val s` is actually wrapped in a hidden class by the REPL (this is how the REPL circumvents the restriction that a `val` can't be declared at the top level).

Inside a method, the `val` definition does not decompile into a "getter" method, but rather into the bytecode necessary to generate a value on the stack. A `lazy val`, on the other hand, always requires a "getter" method which, as such, can be self-referential.