# lazy val v.s. val for recursive stream in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, stream, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I understand the basic of diff between `val` and `lazy val`  .
but while I run across this example, I 'm confused.

The following code is right one. It is a recursion on stream type lazy value.

```
def recursive(): {
     lazy val recurseValue: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: recurseValue.map(_+1) 
     recurseValue
}
```

If I change `lazy val` to `val`. It reports error.

```
def recursive(): {
     //error forward reference failed.
     val recurseValue: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: recurseValue.map(func) 
     recurseValue
}
```

My trace of thought in 2th example by substitution model/evaluation strategy is :

the right hand sight of #:: is **call by name** with that the value shall be of the form :

`1 #:: ?`,

and if  2th element being accessed afterward, it refer to current `recurseValue` value and rewriting it to :

`1 :: ((1 #:: ?) map func) = 
1 :: (func(1) #:: (? map func))`

.... and so on and so on such that the compiler should success.

I don't see any error  when I rewriting it ,is there somthing wrong?

**EDIT:**
CONCLUSION:I found it work fine if the val defined as a field. And I also noticed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962778/when-does-a-stream-need-to-be-lazy?rq=1) about implement of val.  The conclusion is that the val has different implementation in method or field or REPL. That's confusing really.

Comment: Lazy val allow forward reference while non-lazy local val not allowed. Lazy val are actually not reference anything directly, it reference those while it is called later.

Comment: REPL computes every line one after another. So, every lazy val is accessed at once. http://daily-scala.blogspot.ru/2009/09/lazy-val.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That substitution model works for recursion if you are defining *functions*, but you can't define a *variable* in terms of itself unless it is lazy.  All of the info needed to compute the right-hand side must be available for the assignment to take place, so a bit of laziness is required in order to recursively define a variable.

[You probably don't really want to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217222/should-i-use-val-or-def-when-defining-a-stream/13217223#13217223), but just to show that it works for functions:

```
scala> def r = { def x:Stream[Int] = 1#::( x map (_+1) ); x }
r: Stream[Int] 
scala> r take 3 foreach println
1
2
3
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes ,I found it indeed work fine if the val defined as a field. And I also noticed this post about implement of val. The conclusion is that the val has different implementation in method or field or REPL. That's confusing really.